# Personal Maven repository on Bitbucket/GitHub

Tags: android, git, maven, github, bitbucket

Here is my problem. Im traing host my library on Bitbucket repo. For this i create branch 'releases', put in there this files and folders:

```
-com.mygroup
   - myartifact
      - 1.0.0
          - myartifact-1.0.0.aar
          - myartifact-1.0.0.aar.md5
          - myartifact-1.0.0.aar.sh1
          - myartifact-1.0.0.pom
          - myartifact-1.0.0.pom.md5
          - myartifact-1.0.0.pom.sh1
   - maven-metadata.xml
   - maven-metadata.xml.md5
   - maven-metadata.xml.sha1
```

For the next step im add new maven repo:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven{
            url "https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/repositories/myusername/myrepo/raw/releases/"
        }
    }
}
```

And add new dependency:

```
compile 'com.mygroup:myartifact:1.0.0'
```

Nothings work. Repository does not exist: `Failed to resolve: com.mygroup:myartifact:1.0.0`
What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Android Studio can't resolve my dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget about manually configuration your repository and start using [Git Wagon](https://github.com/synergian/wagon-git)

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to add your credentials like this? :

```
maven {
        credentials {
            username "test@gmail.com"
            password "test"
        }
        url "https://bitbucket.org/test/maven-repo/raw/master/repository/"
    }
```

Comment: I made my repository public for debugging. So this not necessary.